# How do you edit a user, who's email username has a hyphen included?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have written a piece of code that looks up user's roles in ASP.NET MVC.  Suffice to say that it is working for most users.  However, if a user has a hyphen in their email address it fails to update the user's details.

For example:

I have performed several tests of username: test@test.com and all the tests came back positive.  However, using the same user, but changing their username test-test@test.com or test@test-test.com and I can recall the user, but I am unable to post any changes.

**Controller Code:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult RoleAddToUser(string UserId, string RoleName)
    {
        User user = context.Users.Where(u => u.Id.Equals(UserId, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
        var userManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var idResult = userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, RoleName);
        ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully !";

        return View("ManageUserRoles");
    }
```

---

**--- Update ---**

Tried adding the following code to my AccountController as recommend, but it didn't seem to work.

```
    public AccountController(UserManager<User> userManager)
    {
        var provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.DpapiDataProtectionProvider("One");
        userManager.UserTokenProvider = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(provider.Create("EmailConfirmation"));
        UserManager = (ApplicationUserManager)userManager;

        UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User>(UserManager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false
        };
    }
```

My ApplicationUser is simply User.

---

**--- Update ---**

Having gone through my code I found in my IdentityConfig.cs:

```
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<User>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
```

This is showing that the AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames has been set and through a few tests is working fine.  So that's not the issue.  The issue appears to be only occuring with email addresses that has a '-' embedded somewhere:

> test@test.com - works fine. Users with this email format can update and edit their own email address.
>
> test@test-test.com - does not work.
>
> test-test@test.com - does not work.

May need to perform more tests.

Any suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726750/identity-email-with-dash-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Thank you, but it sadly didn't work.

Comment: Can You post your updated code where you tried to set AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames as false???

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the flow of your tests? How do you change the username to include hyphen? What error do you get at your action?

Comment: Isaac: Not sure what you need.  Tests include posting new variables to the user account and then removing them.
I change the username via SQL, however I can also simply add a new account with a hyphenated username.
No error message, just no updates on the user account.

Comment: Krish: I followed the instructions as laid out by the hyperlink.  I then attempted several other suggestions from associated links. Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you Debug and see what do you get in the `idResult`? also if posible, can you attach some sort of profiler to your DB and see if any query is being sent to update the role?

Comment: Isaac: I will try that. Just can't understand why it works for users that don't have hyphens in their email addresses. Saying that I have read what Krish has submitted and it suggests that there is a default that only allows alphas and numerics, and the link Krish has submitted advises how to resolve this. Though it didn't work for me the first attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having tried multiple methods to fix the problem with the username, I then tried the more obvious answer.  I have now dropped email address as the username and now users need to create a username (with restrictions on what can be used in place). I have tested it with multiple users and it is working fine.

Thinking about the security, if I had a user's email address and the system required an email address and password to access the site, it would only be a matter of time using hacking methods (brute force etc) that I could access the user's details.

I have also put other counter measures to prevent brute force methods to the site, as a precaution.

Answer (score 2):

I have reproduced this issue in one of my projects. Don't know exactly why Identity does not make the changes (will try and get into it if have some spare time) but you can fix this by wire up a custom validator to your `UserManager` at declaration.

```
manager.UserValidator = new CustomUserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager);
```

And the CustomValidator should look like:

```
public class CustomUserValidator<TUser> : IIdentityValidator<TUser>
    where TUser : class, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser
{
    private static readonly Regex EmailRegex = new Regex(Consts.EmailRegex, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    //in my case EmailRegex = @"^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$"; but you can use your own
    private readonly UserManager<TUser> _manager;

    public CustomUserValidator()
    {
    }

    public CustomUserValidator(UserManager<TUser> manager)
    {
        _manager = manager;
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(TUser item)
    {
        var errors = new List<string>();
        if (!EmailRegex.IsMatch(item.UserName))
            errors.Add("Bad email address");

        if (_manager != null)
        {
            var otherAccount = await _manager.FindByNameAsync(item.UserName);
            if (otherAccount != null && otherAccount.Id != item.Id)
                errors.Add("Email already exists");
        }

        return errors.Any()
            ? IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray())
            : IdentityResult.Success;
    }
}
```

The `ValidateAsync` will be used when validating a new user (and apperantly if making any changes on existing user), and you can apply your own Email Regex and other validations

Comment: Thank you Isaac, I will try this out tomorrow.  Appreciate your efforts.  I'll let you know the outcome. :)

Comment: Isaac: I tried adding the code above, but it didn't seem to make a difference. Can you tell me exactly where it should go please?  I assumed it needed to go into the AccountController.

Comment: The `manager.UserValidator = new CustomUserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager);` should go in your `ApplicationUserManager` `Create` method.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that. Also Email Regex is new to me, so I am looking into that too.

Comment: One of the things I can't get my head around is that: test@test-email.com is a valid form of email.  The hyphen or minus symbol is used frequently in emails. Why have the guys at ASP.NET MVC missed this obvious format? Arghh!

Comment: Ok, a bit closer (I think).  I have checked my code thoroughly and found that the AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames has been set up and that part is working fine.  The only problem that exists is the fact that when updating any account with a username (email) test-test@test.com or test@test-test.com it doesn't work.  Users are able to create the account with no issues.

Comment: Have you tried giving up the `AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames` and using the code I provided?

Comment: Sorry Isaac, but your code works exactly the same way as my:             manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

Comment: this fix perfectly works fr me. I just needed to alter the UserManager to my own implementation. thnks.