# ASP.NET Hyphen in registration email

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

When registering a user with an email that contains a hyphen (that-email@mail.com) the user gets logged correctly to the database in the correct role that he is assigned to. However, when that user logs in to the application he does not see all the features that his role should be able to see, f.x. some buttons or tabs. I do NOT get the error:

> User name that-email@mail.com is invalid, can only contain letters or
>   digits.

when registering.

I have `AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames` set to false

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
{
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    // Configure validation logic for usernames
    manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
    {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        RequireUniqueEmail = true
    };
}
```

and this works for email containing a dot instead of the hyphen (that.email@mail.com), that user can see everything a user of his role should be able to see.

EDIT

After adding suggested code to the `AccountController` as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726750/identity-email-with-dash-in-asp-net-identity) the problem still persists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identity email with dash in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726750/identity-email-with-dash-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up solving my issue was having the user log in with username and password instead of email and password.

**Login.cshtml**

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

And in the Login POST method in `AccountController` set the first parameter as model.UserName:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Additionally I added a simple regex attribute check that forbids hyphens in the username, as having a hyphenated username caused the same problem.

**AccountViewModels.cs**

```
[RegularExpression("[^-]+", ErrorMessage = "Username can not contain a hyphen (-)")]
```

Now the email can still have the hyphen in it and all role related features are visible to the logged in user.